# Installing R packages in Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install fPortfolio using `install.packages("fPortfolio")` on a Google Colab notebook. And I know there are some limitations.

```
Warning message in install.packages("fPortfolio"): 
“installation of package ‘gsl’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("fPortfolio"):
“installation of package ‘Rglpk’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("fPortfolio"):
“installation of package ‘energy’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("fPortfolio"):
“installation of package ‘fAssets’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("fPortfolio"):
“installation of package ‘fPortfolio’ had non-zero exit status”
```

So  I need apt-get some libraries. **But I don't know which ones**. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you provide the name(s) of packages that fail to install it will be easier to get an answer. Also have you checked that you are using the correct runtime? Runtime --> Change runtime type

Comment: OK, I edit with the missing packages.